# System for generating websites

Tags: templates, generator

I searched...can't find any good references.  I have what I think is a pretty simple question:  What are the basic concepts behind a system that allows customers to specify and generate a website, from a choice of style templates?

Say for example I created a simple website consisting of four static HTML pages.  I can make those pages look like anything I want by using different CSS templates...good.

But if I wanted to give my clients an interface that says "hit this button and your site will be generated" -- I don't know what the basics are underneath that idea to make it happen.  Is it simply a matter of creating the directories and copying files?

Before I go down a dumb path I just need some general guidance about how this type of thing is usually done.  There are notable services out there that offer people the ability to sign up for an account, and in "three easy steps" generate a simple website.  I want to learn the theory and basics behind how that is done.

Thanks...

**EDIT:**

I know how to change an existing set of static HTML pages using CSS.  What I want to do is build a true website generator.  You log into my system, pick a theme, hit a button and your site (e.g. www.foo.com or foo.parentsite.com) is ready to use.  I can figure out how to allow customers to change content -- by integrating tinyMCE for example.  I just need the basic concepts behind the "hit a button...generate a new site" idea.

Comment: You mean, how do I make a CMS? AFAIK, it is mostly a translation process, from a limited, tailored templating language to the real languages of the web: HTML, CSS, JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change with javascript the css used. This will change the looks of the current page.
But you need to make multiple css with an unique look.
I suggest you to make a generic css and add the theme of your site into a small css.
The small one should contain only what is unique with this theme.

generic.css => Place content,menu, footer, etc... 
theme1.css => Change background color to red, change text color to blue, etc
theme2.css => Change background color to blue, change text color to blue, etc
theme3.css => Change background color to blue, change text color to red, etc

JQuery Ui allow to change his interface easily.
[Check this and change selected gallery on left](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#ffDefault=Trebuchet+MS,+Tahoma,+Verdana,+Arial,+sans-serif&fwDefault=bold&fsDefault=1.1em&cornerRadius=4px&bgColorHeader=f6a828&bgTextureHeader=12_gloss_wave.png&bgImgOpacityHeader=35&borderColorHeader=e78f08&fcHeader=ffffff&iconColorHeader=ffffff&bgColorContent=eeeeee&bgTextureContent=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityContent=100&borderColorContent=dddddd&fcContent=333333&iconColorContent=222222&bgColorDefault=f6f6f6&bgTextureDefault=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityDefault=100&borderColorDefault=cccccc&fcDefault=1c94c4&iconColorDefault=ef8c08&bgColorHover=fdf5ce&bgTextureHover=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityHover=100&borderColorHover=fbcb09&fcHover=c77405&iconColorHover=ef8c08&bgColorActive=ffffff&bgTextureActive=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityActive=65&borderColorActive=fbd850&fcActive=eb8f00&iconColorActive=ef8c08&bgColorHighlight=ffe45c&bgTextureHighlight=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityHighlight=75&borderColorHighlight=fed22f&fcHighlight=363636&iconColorHighlight=228ef1&bgColorError=b81900&bgTextureError=08_diagonals_thick.png&bgImgOpacityError=18&borderColorError=cd0a0a&fcError=ffffff&iconColorError=ffd27a&bgColorOverlay=666666&bgTextureOverlay=08_diagonals_thick.png&bgImgOpacityOverlay=20&opacityOverlay=50&bgColorShadow=000000&bgTextureShadow=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityShadow=10&opacityShadow=20&thicknessShadow=5px&offsetTopShadow=-5px&offsetLeftShadow=-5px&cornerRadiusShadow=5px)

I don't think you can generate an website than customer will be very satisfy.
There's always something than client want to change.

EDIT: 
You need to create folder on the server.
Put all necessary file with his selected themes into the folder
Configure apache for his domain. Then reload it for the new config.

I suggest you to use PHP or cgi.

The thing I don't know how is to register the domain if available and how to redirect his domain to your ip easily and automated.

Comment: Thanks Jean-Francois it sounds like it's all file manipulation...I will experiment

Comment: @C C Can you share some link for API?

Comment: Sure...start here:  http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/WebHome

Comment: $38 per month for cPanel?  My hosting company provides it already as part of my hosting costs, but the question is will they allow me to make calls to the API...I have to check.

Answer (score 0):

Found something else tonight:  There is a full set of APIs that can be used to gain access to cPanel functionality.  So, almost literally, using their PHP wrapper it looks like only a few lines of code to instantiate a subdomain, set up email accounts, domain pointers, etc.

Looks promising...but being a total noob I have a lot of reading to do...